# React Native justifying views vertically without me setting it to

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, flexbox

I'm experimenting a login screen: https://snack.expo.io/@lucaszanella/login-screen-test-zanella

*(some image sources were removed because I cannot upload them to snack and others I changed to random images from url)*

Open `login_screen/components/Form.js`. Well, as you see, the `UserInput` inputs and `SubmitButton` button are spaced, but I didn't tell them to. I already tried all `justifyContent` properties and they don't even move the components. Looks like they are justified (not even equally).

What is going on? If you know some concept about flexbox that I'm getting wrong please tell me.

Comment: You are passing `flex: 7`to your Form. That's why they are spaced.

Comment: @TimH flex 7 was supposed to be for the form only. Why things inside the form follow it too? Also, if I put the 3 objects inside a       <View style={{flex:1}}> they continue spaced. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Children of a `flexbox` share the parent's flex area in proportions. You have set `Logo` to `flex:3`, `Form` to `flex:7`, and `SignupSection` to `flex:1`. Thus, 7 + 3 + 1 = 11, therefore, `Logo` takes 3/11, `Form` takes 7/11, and `SignupSection` takes 1/11 of the parent's flex area in the specified direction.

Within `Form`, you've set `UserInput` to `flex: 1`. So the children (`UserInput`) of `Form` will equally share (and fill up) the flex area (7/11) that `Form` has acquired from its parent. This is why you see the space between `UserInput`s. To understand this better, try replacing `UserInput`s with simple `View`s with different background colors and you'll see what's going on.

**Solution:** Reduce `flex` on `Form` and apply margins if required.

**EDIT**

Alternatively, you can set fixed `height` (in case of `flexDirection:'column'` of parent) or `width` (in case of `flexDirection:'row'` of parent) to the children.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Why, then, it won't work if I put the 3 objects inside a <View style={{flex:1}}>? The fact that children of a flexbox share the proportions is very strange, shouldn't be like this

Comment: What won't work inside a `View style={{flex:1}}`? And allowing children to share the flex area in proportions is how a flexbox works, that's the basic idea of a flexbox, hence the name. If you don't want that, then you can, alternatively, give fixed `height` or `width` to the children (depending on `flexDirection` of the parent).

Comment: Additionally, please refer the last line of your question. @TimH and I have only tried to explain the concept of flexbox that has not be applied in the code.

Comment: I see no reason for justifyContent:"flex-start" not working inside form.

Comment: I think I know why it sounded real strange to me that the children always gets spaced. It only happends if they're flexboxes. I didn't need them to do, it was just an accident. You said basically that, but I didn't understand. I simply took off the flex from them and it worked. Thank you