# issue with flex dimension in react-native

Tags: react-native

I am trying to align my layout screen with flexbox,but there is unwanted space in between component children.

```
import React,{Component} from 'react';
import { View,Image,StyleSheet,Dimensions } from 'react-native';
import { Card,Button,Avatar } from 'react-native-elements';
export default class WelcomePage extends Component {
    render() {
        const {navigate}=this.props.navigation
        return (
            <View style={{flexDirection:'column',flex:1,alignItems:'center',justifyContent: 'flex-start'}}>
            <Avatar
              width={Dimensions.get('window').width}
              height={Dimensions.get('window').width*500/500}
              containerStyle={{flex:80}}
              imageProps={{resizeMode:'cover'}}
              source={require('../assets/images/logo.png')}
              onPress={() => console.log("Works!")}
              activeOpacity={0.7}
            />
            <View style={{flexDirection:'row',flex:20}}>
                <Button  large title='LOGIN' icon={{name: 'user-secret',type:'font-awesome'}} containerViewStyle={{borderRadius:5}} borderRadius={5} />
                <Button  large title='REGISTER' icon={{name: 'user-plus',type:'font-awesome'}} onPress={() => navigate('register')} containerViewStyle={{borderRadius:5}} borderRadius={5} />
            </View> 
            </View>
        )
    }
}
```

**output**
[image]

in the above output you can see an unwanted space at the start and in between the button and the image component.what is the issue here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have

- Added the `containerStyle` to be `flex: 80`, but your `avatar's height = screen width`, *therefore is aligned to the center and show's some space*.

Therefore you need to remove the

```
height={Dimensions.get('window').width*500/500}
```

and add the `flex` to the image, *to cover the entire flex* as

```
avatarStyle={{flex:80}}

<Avatar
                    width={Dimensions.get('window').width}
                    containerStyle={{flex:80}}
                    avatarStyle={{flex:80}}
                    imageProps={{resizeMode: 'cover'}}
                    source={require('../assets/images/logo.png')}
                    onPress={() => console.log("Works!")}
                    activeOpacity={0.7}
                />
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want `Avatar` to have a specific height to fill up vertically then

1- Remove flex from `Avatar` and its sibling `View`.

2- Change `500/500` accordingly in `height` prop of your `Avatar` or you can try `Dimensions.get('window').height`. *Reason:* The expression `500/500` evaluates to `1`, which effectively makes your `Avatar` a square with `width` and `height` equal to `Dimensions.get('window').width`.

Alternatively, if `Avatar/Image` size is as intended, then you can refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49704039/react-native-justifying-views-vertically-without-me-setting-it-to/49704927#49704927) for bit more explanation on behavior of children of a `flexbox`, if you want.